# Running node-red application

Tags: node-red

When I want to run node-red, It started to show the error that the Error loading settings file.

```
Error loading settings file: \Users\<User-Name>\.node-red\settings.js
```

Comment: Had you edited the `settings.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Create a Settings.js file in that location, Which worked for me.

```
file: \Users<User-Name>\.node-red\settings.js
(create an empty settings.js file there in that location)
```

Comment: There is something missing here, Node-RED will copy a standard template version of `settings.js` to the `userDir` on startup when the file is not found. Creating an empty file shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and install the new one.
If you done with downloading Node.js with any version, just try this.

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red <br>
npm install node-red-dashboard <br>
node-red
```

You must execute these in your folder path which you gonna download node-red.
For me, I downloaded node-red in my local computer. ( C\Users\admin\Desktop )